# How can I make the keyboard not close when opening a new activity?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-activity, xamarin.android

I added text selection actions, but when they are executed, the keyboard closes.How to make sure that the keyboard does not close?

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJKRB.png)

```
<activity android:name="app1.droid.BoldActivity" android:label="Bold">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

public class BoldActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.StateAlwaysVisible);

            var text = Intent.GetCharSequenceExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraProcessText);
            var read = Intent.GetBooleanExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraProcessTextReadonly, false);

            if (!read && text != null)
            {
                var outIntent = new Android.Content.Intent();
                outIntent.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraProcessText, HtmlCompat.FromHtml("<b>" + text + "</b>", 0));
                base.OnStop();
                SetResult(Result.Ok, outIntent);
            }


            Finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to use the inputmethodmanager to force the soft keyboard to show.

Comment: Yes

`InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.WindowToken, 0);
imm.ToggleSoftInput(ShowFlags.Forced, 0);`

Comment: this code i use in custom render Editor

Comment: You can try to use `imm.ShowSoftInput`, not `imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow`.

Comment: I already used ShowSoftInput, the result is slightly different, but it does not achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: I have done a sample with xamarin.android, when I selected the text, the soft keybord will not disappear. Did you mean when you click the bold in the menu, the soft keyboard will disappear?

Comment: Yes, exactly when I press the bold keyboard disappears. Thanks a lot for trying to help. I have now found another solution that solved my problem. As soon as I finish it, I'll post the answer.